# Pervasive PSQL: Select with order by inside select

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql

I have an query with an select inside select.
The select inside the select has a order by.

The problem is that Pervasive gives a error on the order by.

The query:

```
select itemID,item1,item2 from "table2" where itemID in (select top 1 itemID from "table1" order by ID desc)
```

The error:

```
[Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface]Syntax Error: select itemID,item1,item2 from "table2" where itemID in (select top 1 itemID from "table1" order<< ??? >> by ID desc)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tested with PSQL v11 and saw the same error.  I have not tested with PSQL 12.  Looking at the documentation, it seems that ORDER BY should be supported in the "IN" select query. You'll probably want to contact Actian for support.

Comment: Okay, thank you for testing it! I will make two different queries of it, its faster than waiting for an bug fix.